# Add Custom Slug Tags Per Page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, slug, permalinks

So I want to be able to have dynamic slugs for my Woocommerce "My Account" page, basically the current format is `http://www.example.com/my-account/`but I want to make the parent page the Buddypress members page and add the user's username to the slug as well so I can have the format like `http://www.example.com/members/%username%/my-account/`so does anyone know how to do this to add in custom slug tags and then add them to specific pages?